# In AEM, if we accidentally delete out of the box bundle. what will happen and how will you retrieve the deleted bundle

Tags: osgi, aem, osgi-bundle

In AEM,  if i accidentally delete the OOTB bundle from systems/console.
How do i retrieve it.
I think restarting the instance would work.
It is fine if you are doing it it in local.
What about higher environments.
can some one advise

Comment: which ootb bundle you are talking about because thier are many bundles in systems/console?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you can get it by restarting the instance. More likely you will have to get it from another stable environment first (or start a fresh instance and look in `crx-quickstart/launchpad/felix`), and then restart. This is assuming that the instance was able to shut down safely. Then put the missing bundle here: `crx-quickstart/launchpad/felix` and restart. Take a look at the logs and hopefully, all of them will be active.

Access to the bundles console should be very restricted because operations here can cause damage your whole instance or cause performance issues if inadvertently you stop, delete or restart certain bundles.